# Class that implements an interface can't use itself insted of Object in Equals

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I'm trying to inherit an interface that contains the method equals which receives another object, but in the class, I'm trying to use the class type, eg: class Grade, and override the method with Grade other.
Correct me if I am wrong, any class inherits from the Object class in java.
I might have not understood the interfaces too well.
Thanks!

```
public interface Comparable {

    int Bigger(String ... args);
    
    boolean Equals(Object other);
    
}
```

```
    @Override
    public boolean Equals(Grade other) {
        if(other.getGrade() == this.getGrade() && other.getPoints() == this.getPoints() && other.getSubject() == this.getSubject())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `Equals(Object other)` is over**loaded** by `Equals(Grade other)`. Please follow naming conventions...

Comment: @ernest_k OP clearly *wants* to override it, though; hence the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Presumably. But the lesson that the OP needs is elsewhere... see their comment about *"any class inherits from the Object class in java"* in the context of method overriding. With that said, maybe they don't even know that they don't need the method at all... `Object.equals` seems to be the obvious method to use for this.

Comment: The equals() method uses ``public boolean equals(Object o)``. You can get some odd and difficult-to-debug errors if you use a type other than Object.

Answer (score 2):

Use generics:

```
interface Comparable<T> {
    // …
    boolean Equals(T other);
}
```

```
class Grade implements Comparable<Grade> {
    // …

    @Override
    public boolean Equals(Grade other) {
        return other.getGrade() == getGrade()
            && other.getPoints() == getPoints()
            && other.getSubject() == getSubject());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

forgot about generic programming,

```
public interface Comparable<T>{

int Bigger(String ... args);

boolean Equals(T other);
}

public class Grade implements Comparable<Grade>{
@Override
public boolean Equals(Grade other) {
    if(other.getGrade() == this.getGrade() && other.getPoints() == this.getPoints() && other.getSubject() == this.getSubject())
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```